# Docker Network Drive EXTRA string=is not a valid Windows path

Tags: docker

I have the following command to run my docker container:

```
docker run --privileged -d -v C:\Users\admin\Documents\config:/config -v \\QNAP-NAS\Media\P2P\done\:/downloads -e "VPN_ENABLED=yes" -e "LAN_NETWORK=192.168.86.0/24" -e "NAME_SERVERS=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4" -p 8080:8080 -p 8999:8999 -p 8999:8999/udp qbittorrentvpn
```

Specifically:

```
-v \\QNAP-NAS\Media\P2P\done\:/downloads
```

However, when I run the command I receive the following error.

```
Error response from daemon: \\QNAP-NAS\Media\P2P\done\%!(EXTRA string=is not a valid Windows path).
```

What is the correct way to format my path?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar issue, I tried changing the path given to:

```
 -v //QNAP-NAS//Media//P2P//done//:/downloads
```

Comment: i am using docker for desktop on windows 10 machine, for me its working with normal windows path like c:\xml_files but when i try to prodide network shared path it can not mount it. and when looked at the mapped folder in container it show empty. any help???

Comment: I would check these things : 1. linux or windows container on docker. Would recommend windows as stated by the windows path. 2. Check permissions to your folder. If you cannot find a solution, raising a new question would help.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something similar in gitbash in windows. I first got the path from powershell by pwd then I copied that path to gitbash with the double quotes. So in my case `docker run ... -v "<pwd host path>":<container path>`